# Showing Err For correct Code:'Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise'

Tags: reactjs, cypress, react-testing-library, cypress-testing-library, react-testing

I have entered the code right, and it worked too. But now i dont know why i am getting same error on different lines of code each time i test. The error comes at the chained commands.
Sometimes its a chained Cy.find commands while sometimes its some other chained command.

[image]

**::EDIT::**
I have changed the code a bit tried doing different methods etc, but still getting the same error. So the code below(Code-1) is the cypress commands to execute the integration test. Since this particular test values might change so I made another file to pass all those values as a single object(Code-2).

FYI the code worked first time, when i didn't have Code-2, ie: when i manually inserted all those values.

Code-1:

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
import { cropFileName, testData } from '../test_case/quoteGen' 

describe('waste-Quote-Generation-for-Permanant-Client', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/login');
  });
it('user login', () => {
    // login
    
    cy.findByPlaceholderText(/username/i).type(testData.username)
    cy.findByPlaceholderText(/password/i).type(testData.pass)
    cy.get('.newLoginPanelBtn').click();
    // navigate to 'Sales' tab.

    cy.findByRole('link', {
        name: /sales/i,
        timeout: 5000
      })
      .should('be.visible')
      .click({ force : true });

    // Click on 'Generate Quote'
    cy.findByRole('link', {
        name: /generate quote/i,
        timeout: 5000
      }).click({ force : true })

      // cy.wait(3000)


    // Select Template
    cy.findByRole('link', {
        name: /template/i,
        timeout: 5000
      })
      .should('be.visible')
      .click({ force : true })

    // Select Client
    if(testData.clientType!=='create')
      cy.findByText(testData.client).click()
    else{
      cy.get('#newSiteName').click();
      cy.get('#newSiteName').type(testData.client);
      cy.get('#newSiteEmail').click();
      cy.get('#newSiteEmail').type(testData.clientEmail);
      cy.get('#createNewSite').click();
      cy.wait(200);
      cy.findByText(testData.client).click()
    } 
      
    // Choose Type of Waste 
    if(testData.wasteTypeOpt.newName!==null){
      cy.findByText(testData.wasteTypeOpt.name).click()
      cy.get('#towAddNewBtn').click();
    }else{
      cy.findByText(testData.wasteTypeOpt.name).click()
      cy.get('#towContinueBtn').click();
    }
    


    // Check if Job Card Exist
    if(testData.jobCard.new){
      cy.findByText(/create job card/i).click(); 
      // Add Job Card and Verify Job Card 
      cy.get('.jobCardDiv1 .jobCardDivInpContentDiv:nth-child(6) .jobCardDivInp').click();
      cy.get('.jobCardDiv1 .jobCardDivInpContentDiv:nth-child(6) .jobCardDivInp').type('1234');
    
      cy.get('#jobCardDate > span:nth-child(2)').click();
      cy.get('.MuiButton-textPrimary:nth-child(2) > .MuiButton-label').click();
      cy.get('.newJobCardBtnActive').click({ force : true });
    }
      cy.get('#job-cards-list > div:first').click();
      cy.get('.newJobCardBtnActive').click({ force : true })
    
    // Select Attachments
    cy.get('#attach-file-list').children().each((_,index, collection) => {
      if(index!==3 && testData.attachments.includes(index))
        collection.eq(index).click()
    })
    cy.get('#attach-file-list').children().findByText(cropFileName('safety attachments',25,5,5)).click()
    setTimeout(() => {
      cy.findByText(/add to attachment/i).click();  
    }, 3000);
    


    cy.get('#quoteEditorButton').click();
    // Click on 'Quote'
    cy.get('#updateScopeOfWorkButton').click();


    cy.get('#editTableEditorModal').find('tr').eq(0).then(tbrow => {
      testData.scopeofWork.map((el, k) => {
        cy.wrap(tbrow).findAllByPlaceholderText('Description').dblclick()
        cy.wrap(tbrow).findAllByPlaceholderText('Description').type(el.descp)

        cy.wrap(tbrow).find('.navbar-button').click();
        cy.findAllByText(el.tow).click()

        cy.wrap(tbrow).findByPlaceholderText('volume').dblclick()
        cy.wrap(tbrow).findByPlaceholderText('volume').type(el.vol)
      
        cy.wrap(tbrow).findByPlaceholderText('Unit').dblclick()
        cy.wrap(tbrow).findByPlaceholderText('Unit').type(el.unit)
      
        cy.wrap(tbrow).findByPlaceholderText('pricing').dblclick()
        cy.wrap(tbrow).findByPlaceholderText('pricing').type(el.pricing)
        if(k<testData.scopeofWork.length-1)
          cy.get('#addNewRowScopeOfWork').click()
        return 0
      })
      
    })

   cy.get('#updateTableModalButton').click();


   cy.get('#continueGNRTQT').click()
    // Insert mail id, Click on Generate Quote. 

cy.get('.quote-cnrf-to-layout:nth-child(2) .quote-cnrf-emails-input').click();
cy.get('.quote-cnrf-to-layout:nth-child(2) .quote-cnrf-emails-input').type(testData.email);
cy.get('.quote-cnrf-to-layout:nth-child(3) .quote-cnrf-emails-input').click();
cy.get('.quote-cnrf-emails-input:nth-child(2)').click();
cy.get('.quote-cnrf-emails-input:nth-child(2)').type('asdf');
cy.get('.quote-cnrf-emails-textarea').click();
cy.get('.quote-cnrf-emails-textarea').type('asdf');
if(testData.sendType)
  cy.get('#generateandsend').click();
else 
  cy.get('#approvedQuote').click();
cy.get('.swal2-confirm').click();
    })
    
})
```

Code 2:

```
export const testData = {
    username    :   'Tester',
    pass        :   '##tester001',
    tabType     :   "",
    template    :   /template/i, 
    clientType  :   'permanent',    // permanent, temporary, create
    client      :   /geolocated site/i, 
    clientEmail :   null,
    wasteTypeOpt:   {
        name        :   /dilution pit/i, 
        newName     :   null,       },
    jobCard     :   {
        new         :   false,
    },
    attachments :   [],
    scopeofWork :   [
        {   descp   :   'asdf',
            tow     :   /grease/i,
            vol     :   '10',
            unit    :   '5',
            pricing :   '2'
       }
    ],
    email       :   'asdf@asdf.com',
    sendType    :   true    // true => 'Generate and send', false => 'Approved Quote'
    
}

export const cropFileName = (str, len, frnt, lst) => {
    RegExp.escape = function(string) {
        return string.replace(/[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
      };
    let lastIndx = str ? str.length : 0
    if(lastIndx <= len){
        return new RegExp(str, "i")
    }
    else{
        console.log('NewREgExp=>',new RegExp(RegExp.escape(str.substring(0,frnt)+'...'+str.substring(lastIndx-lst,lastIndx))))
        return new RegExp(RegExp.escape(str.substring(0,frnt)+'...'+str.substring(lastIndx-lst,lastIndx)))
    }

}

// ENCASE STRING in CASE INSENSITIVE \i
```

The 'cropFileName' function is used to manage all those long names. The long names will be snipped in CSS or JS by frontend, 'cropFileName' helps to determine the length of the string and decide whether to add '.' in between the string for RegEx conversion.

Comment: Add the code you tried in your question.

Comment: I Have just edited the question. Hope it helps you. :)